# Получить pid процессов по имени скрипта

Tags: php, linux

Нужно получить `pid` 2х или более скриптов, работающих в фоновом режиме. Затем по их `pid` они будут закрыты через `kill $pid` но вопрос - как их получить зная имя процесса ? Например я использую `system('ps aux | grep php');` что бы получить вообще все процессы и вижу примерно такой ответ :

```
username 676878 100 0.0 296980 14372 ? R 13:04 3:27 /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php/home/username/Business_Logic/testProc.php 
username 676943 99.8 0.0 296980 14372 ? R 13:04 3:25 /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php/home/username/Business_Logic/testProc.php 
username 693011 1.0 0.0 461388 15888 ? Ss 13:08 0:00 lsphp 
username 693146 0.0 0.0 462164 6768 ? Ss 13:08 0:00 lsphp:/home/username/public_html/index.php 
username 693147 0.0 0.0 12228 1264 ? S 13:08 0:00 sh -c ps aux | grep php
username 693149 0.0 0.0 8492 696 ? S 13:08 0:00 grep php
```

Два верхних процесса мне и нужно убить. Однако если дальше ввести :

```
$proc_str = exec('ps aux | grep /home/username/Business_Logic/testProc');
```

Я увижу в ответе совершенно другой `pid` :

```
username 729968 0.0 0.0 8492 704 ? S 13:13 0:00 grep /home/username/Business_Logic/testProc
```

Предпологалось, забить в `$proc_str` `pid` нужного процесса и убить, но это не приводит к желаемому эфекту - процессы по прежднему работают.

UPD
Процесс, который должен быть закончен запускаю несколько раз так :

```
system('php /home/usernam/Business_Logic/testProc.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

Далее, что бы убить :

```
exec('Killall testProc.php'); // ||
exec('Killall testProc');     // ||
exec('Killall  /home/username/Business_Logic/testProc.php');
```

В итоге процессы продолжают висеть. только `exec('kill 568454');` помогло.

UPD_2

```
exec('pkill -f proc_name');
```

Эта комманда помогла, убивает все процессы разом `proc_name.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что Вам пора узнать о командах pkill, которая может убить процесс по имени, killall, которая может убить много процессов по имени или pgrep, который собственно возвращает pid процесса по его имени или pidof (который ищет прямо по имени). В убунте эти команды обычно находятся в пакете procps, в генте - sys-process/procps

Comment: Не работает, скрипт по прежднему запущен. пробовал по разному - с расширением и без, с полным именем (вкл путь) и без нути. убились процессы только при указании pid каждого и kill

Comment: во первых, killall пишется с маленькой буковки, а во вторых, ему как и обычному kill, желательно передать сигнал. Но думаю, что Вам все таки нужен pkill

Comment: `exec('killall -s SIGKILL testProc.php');` увы тоже не то. `pkill` не останавливает не одного запущенного процесса. странно, даже pidof ничего не возвращает.

Comment: 1. Убиваете под `username`? `whoami` чтобы увидеть кто вы. Вы не можете убивать процессы других пользователей, если не root. 2. Чем занимается скрипт? Если ожидает ввода-вывода, это сисемный вызов, вы через kill и другие киллы его не убьете. [Объяснение](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/what-if-kill-9-does-not-work)

Comment: `ps aux` в колонке STAT показывает что делает процесс. Если `D` - ждет ввод-вывод, в этот момент сигнал `kill -9` не будет срабатывать немедленно. [Подробнее](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360252/what-do-the-stat-column-values-in-ps-mean). У вас `R`, значит прибить можно, почему у вас не получается... См 2 вопроса выше

Comment: @TotalPusher спасибо уже разобрался.

Comment: @Сергей, значит напишите решение, чтобы им могли воспользоваться другие

Comment: @TotalPusher в вопросе UPD_2 решение. или вы имеете в виду как ответ оформить ?

Comment: Да, сделайте в виде ответа, если несложно

Answer (score 2):

В итоге мне помогла следующая команда :

```
exec('pkill -f proc_name');
```

При нескольких запущенных экземплярах скрипта `proc_name.php` она завершает сразу все.